# Re-create channel with same permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to create a bot that re-creates a channel with the same permissions.

So my current code re-creates the channel fine in the same position, NSFW value, etc. but it doesn't put the permissions of the old channel into the new one :/

I've been searching the whole day but couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know that Discord.js had a [.clone method for GuildChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=clone)

This is more easier now based on the documentation :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this could help you:

`recreatedchannel.replacePermissionOverwrites({ overwrites: firstChannel.permissionOverwrites });`

You basically overwrite the permissions of the new channel with the permissions of the channel you are recreating. Always worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

**Question**

I don't think this is possible. And anyways couldn't you just clone the channel. The reasoning behind the bot I don't really understand. Will you tell me the reasoning. Is your discord server a roleplay server?

You can see how to clone a server at [Facebook Pro Tippy Clone Channel](https://www.facebook.com/discordapp/videos/pro-tippy-you-can-clone-channels-discuss-the-yearly-ryze-rework-without-redoing-/1155056227895439/)!

Comment: Why did you put a Facebook related link in your answer? The reason of what I am doing btw is to clear the chat perfectly instead of purging all the messages which won't work in most of the cases due to the Discord limits.

Comment: Oh! I see, well my anwser can be disregarded then